# Magento - 'samples_title' Product attribute

Tags: magento

Magento - for what is the Product attribute 'samples_title' used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a Downloadable Product in Magento, it is the title of your Sample download -- a preview of what you're selling.  You can upload a sample and set a title for it that gets displayed on the product view page.

See `Admin -> Manage Products -> Add Product`, then select `Downloadable Product`, then click `Downloadable Information` and select the `Samples` tab.